# Where can be seen the Task Documentation in the web

Tags: airflow

According to [the Airflow md docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/dags.html#dag-task-documentation), you can add documentation to each task in a dag. I've tried to add that, but I cannot see where the docs are being showed up in the dag (in the Airflow web).

```
dag = DAG(
    "my_dag",
    start_date=pendulum.datetime(2021, 1, 1, tz="UTC"),
    schedule_interval="@daily",
    catchup=False,
)

t = BashOperator("foo", dag=dag)
t.doc_md = """\
#Title"
Here's a [url](www.airbnb.com)
"""

Where can I see it?
```

Comment: Did you check in the Task Instance details?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule yes, it does not appear in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that in version `2.0.0` it has not been developed, so it cannot possibly add be added

Answer (score 0):

You can see that in the Task Instance details page.

[image: Screenshot of the task instance details page]

Comment: thx for answering. what version of airflow are you using? and another question, isn't that dag doc? i'm looking for task doc

Comment: I'm using version 2.2.5 for this example. That is the task instance doc not the dag doc.

Comment: I'm using 2.0.0 and with that, it cannot be seen :/